# I want to read input from file then scrapping results with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I need to scrape website data by entering `userId` and fetching all data returned into a CSV file. So I created a CSV file that contain all `Id`s.

How can I add `id` as input and wait till the data loads? I need the following:

1. Enter input from CSV into the forum
2. Load the data
3. Scrape results for 1000 users

Here's my  code currently:

```
DRIVER_PATH = '/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get('https://g12-result.moe.gov.eg/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.maximize_window()
#read CSV file that contains seat numbers
csv_file = open('/Id.csv','r',newline='')
# Enter list of id 
idText = driver.find_element("id","SeatingNo")
idText.send_keys(870000)
submit = driver.find_element("xpath","//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Image:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scrape site with anti forgery token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73589047/scrape-site-with-anti-forgery-token)

Comment: yes but how can I get data for list of Ids? @RJ Adriaansen

Comment: see below for example code!

Answer (score 0):

See code below on how to process a csv file with ids using [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) and [pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/):

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
import time

# first get the request verification token
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
SeatingNo = '870000'
res = scraper.get("https://g12-result.moe.gov.eg/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
__RequestVerificationToken = soup.find(type="hidden")['value']


def get_data(row):
    data = {'SeatingNo': row['id'], '__RequestVerificationToken': __RequestVerificationToken}
    res = scraper.post("https://g12-result.moe.gov.eg/", data=data)
    dfs = pd.read_html(res.text, index_col=0) # extract tables to pandas dataframes
    dfs = [i.T.reset_index(drop=True) for i in dfs] # transpose the dataframes
    time.sleep(1.5) # sleep for a while to avoid being rate limited 
    return pd.concat([row, pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).iloc[0]]) # return the concatenated tables appended to the dataframe row

df = pd.DataFrame([870000, 330814], columns=['id']) # dummy dataframe, replace with df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv') and update row['id'] above with the right id column name
df = df.apply(get_data, axis=1)
df.to_csv('output.csv') # store dataframe as csv
```

Ouput:

|  | id | رقم الجلوس | الإسم | المدرسة | المديرية | الإدارة | اسم اللجنة | عنوان اللجنة | الهاتف | اللغة العربية | اللغة الأجنبية الأولى | اللغة الأجنبية الثانية | الأحياء | الجيولوجيا وعلوم البيئة | الكيمياء | الفيزياء | المجموع الكلى | التربية الدينية | التربية الوطنية | الإقتصاد والإحصاء |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 870000 | 870000 | خالد نادي محمود محمد | منازل إدارة دشنا | قنــــــــا | دشنا | لجنة النظام والمراقبة قطاع اسيوط أ | معهد التربية الفكرية بأسيوط - خلف مديرية الزراعه | 0882305164 | 41 | 32 | 35 | 30 | 30 | 16 | 30 | 214 | إجتاز | إجتاز | إجتاز |
| 1 | 330814 | 330814 | زينب احمد محمد عبدالله اللهلوبي | الماى الثانوية المشتركة | المنوفية | شبين الكوم | لجنة النظام والمراقبة قطاع القاهرة ج | مدرسة الحلمية الاعدادية القديمة بنين- 1 شارع مصطفى فاضل من شارع بورسعيد - السيدة زينب | 0223928106 | 53 | 35 | 39 | 35 | 42 | 30 | 30 | 264 | 19 | 22 | 33 |

Comment: work perfectly but while trying to add the CSV file it not work

df= pd.read_csv('/id.csv', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['id']) # dummy dataframe, replace with df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv') and update row['id'] above with the right id column name
df = df.apply(get_data, axis=1)
df = df.to_csv('output.csv')

Comment: `df= pd.read_csv('/id.csv', header=None)`looks for the file in the root of your system. If you put the file in the same folder as your script you can run `df= pd.read_csv('id.csv', header=None)`. By the way, if there are no headers in the csv file (as `header=None` suggests) you can name them by index, eg. `df= df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'id'})`